# VLC shows all subtitles only on first frame

Tags: windows-10, vlc-media-player

I'm using VLC v3.0.3 on Windows 10

When a video starts I see ALL subtitles immediately and after dosen't work as expected.

This is a .srt file for example.

```
1
0:00:00.000 --> 0:00:04.020
Text 1

2
0:00:04.020 --> 0:00:06.060
Text 2

3
0:00:06.060 --> 0:00:09.050
Text 3

4
0:00:09.050 --> 0:00:14.050
Text 4

5
0:00:14.050 --> 0:00:16.060
Text 5

6
0:00:16.060 --> 0:00:19.040
Text 6

7
0:00:19.040 --> 0:00:22.070
Text 7

8
0:00:22.070 --> 0:00:24.060
Text 8

9
0:00:24.060 --> 0:00:28.060
Text 9
```

**EDIT**

The problem seems to be the space character after each line of text!

Answer (score -1):

To put milliseconds, it's not '.' (point) but ',' (comma) :

```
1
0:00:00,000 --> 0:00:04,020
Text 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I tried it but not work

Comment: Oh, well, is it UTF8 or Windows-1252 encoded ? Is the last line blank too ?
source [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubRip)

Comment: All my srt's are Unicode, format looks correct if you use comma as suggested by GLCraft

Comment: I tried changing all the "." in "," and removing the final blank line. The file is UTF-8 encoded. Nothing works :(